# I am generating a graph to show the temperature change in Pfywald in the past 30 years

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, geocoding, chart

I am using my code in the last project I have done and trying to change the variable to generate a time series chart of temperature in Pfywald in the past 30 years.Here is my code and my error is

> "Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating
> over an unbounded image."

```
var Pfywald = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY')
    .filterDate('1990-02-01', '2020-02-01')
    .select('mean_2m_air_temperature');    


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection:Pfywald,
  region:Pfywald,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500 
});


 chart.setOptions({
  title: 'The peak time of Drought in California between 2012-2016',
  hAxis: {'title':'Date'},
  vAxis:{'title':'temperature'},
});



chart.style().set({
  position: 'bottom-right',
  width: '500px',
  height: '300px'
});
Map.add(chart);

var usdmColors = "000080,0000d9,4000ff,8000ff,0080ff,00ffff,00ff80,80ff00,daff00,ffff00,fff500,ffda00,ffb000,ffa400,ff4f00,ff2500,ff0a00,ff00ff";


var PyLayer = ui.Map.Layer(Pfywald, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'Py');
Map.layers().add(PyLayer);
Map.setCenter(7.5826, 46.283);



var label = ui.Label('Click a point on the chart to show the image for that date.');
Map.add(label);

chart.onClick(function(xValue, yValue, seriesName) {
  if (!xValue) return;  
  
  var equalDate = ee.Filter.equals('system:time_start', xValue);
  var image = ee.Image(Pfywald_climate.filter(equalDate).first()); 
  var pdsi_z_Layer = ui.Map.Layer(image, {
    min: 224,
    max: 304,
    palette: usdmColors
  });
  Map.layers().reset([CaLayer, pdsi_z_Layer]); // 


  label.setValue((new Date(xValue)).toUTCString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```js
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection:Pfywald,
  region:Pfywald,   // <- This is not a valid region
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500 
});
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-chart-image-series), the `region` parameter should be either a `Feature`, `FeatureCollection`, or `Geometry` so that Earth Engine knows what area to calculate the mean temperature over. You are passing in `Pfywald`, which is an `ImageCollection`. You should replace that with one of the expected types above, either by loading it from a `FeatureCollection` or drawing a polygon on the map and using that.

Comment: I have add a polygon  (named Feature ), and fill it in the region.                                         
 var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: Pfywald
  region:Feature,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500 
});

Comment: Looking at the code you added in your [follow-up question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468359/pfywald-i-have-changed-the-feature-and-there-is-a-new-error), the problem is how you defined the `Feature`. The north and south coordinates are identical, which means that the geometry has no area and didn't extract any pixels. You have a valid `Feature` defined in your "Geometry Imports" tab, so you can remove that line from your code and it will work. Try this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e21a6cdf86dccc821e89027dbdf39877